# Add vertical strut to Beamer Metropolis' footer

Tags: beamer, positioning, beamer-metropolis, strut

The `beamer` theme `metropolis` includes an option to show frame numbers as a fraction of total frames. But it does not add a vertical strut for the eventuality that someone (me!!) would add additional text to the `frame footer` template. When comparing the numbered slides in the main document and the unnumbered in the appendix, then this causes the additional text to jump annoyingly. The jump is even more pronounced when I build the MWE with pdfLaTeX instead of with XeLaTeX as in the screenshot.

How would I go about to add the needed vertical strut to prevent the jumping? I know that I could add `\setbeamertemplate{frame numbering}{\vphantom{/}}` after `\appendix`, but I would really prefer to include the fix in the preamble rather than adding things in the `document` environment.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{metropolis}
\metroset{numbering=fraction}
\begin{document}
  {
    \setbeamertemplate{frame footer}{Some random text}
    \begin{frame}[label=slide1]{Slide 1}
    \end{frame}
  }

  \appendix

  {
    \setbeamertemplate{frame footer}{Some random text}
    \begin{frame}[label=slide2]{Slide 2}
    \end{frame}
  }
\end{document}
```

[image: Animated MWE to emphasize the jumping footer text]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution will remove the observed jump in  the text, even when  descenders are present.

LuaLateX using the Fira fonts

[image: xl]

pdfLaTex using cm fonts

[image: pl]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{metropolis}
\metroset{numbering=fraction}

\setbeamerfont{frame footer}{size=\scriptsize\strut,series=\normalfont} % added <<<<<<<<<<<

\begin{document}
    {%
        \setbeamertemplate{frame footer}{Some random text (1)}
        \begin{frame}[label=slide1]{Slide 1}
        \end{frame}
    }
    
    \appendix
    
    {%
        \setbeamertemplate{frame footer}{Some random text 2}
        \begin{frame}[label=slide2]{Slide 2}
        \end{frame}
    }

\end{document}
```

Comment: Is the strut computed using `\normalsize` when `\strut` precedes `\scriptsize`?

Comment: @Fredrik P In the general case you are right. The right way is to use `<fontsize>\strut`. I updated the answer.
 
In this case, when `\strut` precedes `fontsize` it happens to be generated for scriptsize, like the  page number.
  
  The main point is to insert the same vertical space with depth, in the non apendix  frames  and in the appendix frames to eliminante their respective disalignment when  the text  lacks descenders. 
  
  Notice how both texts move up, through a different distance to line up.